# Even sum & Odd product of a list, Swi-Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a list of numbers and I have to calculate the sum of the Even numbers and the product of the Odd numbers of the same list. I'm new in prolog and this is my code so far:

```
l_odd_even([],0).
l_odd_even([H|T], Odd, [H|Etail], Sum) :-
    H rem 2 =:=0,
    split(T, Odd, Etail),
    Sum = H + Etail.
l_odd_even([H|T], [H|Otail], Even, Prod) :-
    H rem 2 =:=1,
    split(T, Otail, Even),
    Prod = H * Otail.
```

Can anyone help me here ? And I'd like some examples in order to test if the code works.

Comment: What do you need help with? Is it not working? What is the output you're getting? (I can't help because I don't know Prolog).

Comment: This is the second time you've posted this problem. Once is adequate.

Comment: @lurker: Please flag such cases. It helps a lot to find out which one is the "original" and which the duplicate.